# What's the proper way to update parent/child entities in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Ef 4 code first and have a parent table with a child

When I update the parent, I notice that the child is not updated, rather new entries are created (old ones are not deleted).

My update method looks like so:

```
IEFRepository<Parent> repo = new EFRepository<Parent>( context );
var parent = repo.GetSingle(m => m.parentId.Equals(updatedParent.parentId));

parent.Child = updatedParent.Child;  //this is creating a new record in the db, not overwriting the existing

repo.Update(parent);
```

If I break out the child properties in the update method like below it solves the duplicate entry problem, but creates other issues elsewhere (primarily with validating null entries).

```
parent.Child.property = updatedParent.Child.property;
```

I also tried creating an UpdateChild(), and calling that from UpdateParent(), but got essentially the same result as breaking out the individual child properties

Is there a proper way to control this behavior and force EF to overwrite the child entity instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Can you give more details on exactly the change you're trying to make?  It's hard to follow from this description, at least for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a list of childs in a context and [remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) old child from your context when you don't need it anymore.